# java DynamoDBMapper - partially mapped entities - amount of Read Capacity Units

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does java DynamoDB load whole Items when the @DynamoDBTable annotated class maps only a subset of their attributes?

example: "Product" table, holding items with these attributes:
id, name, description. I would like to get the names of several products, without loading the description (which would be a huge amount of data).

Does this code load description from DynamoDB?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Product")
public class ProductName {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.S)
    public UUID getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(UUID id) { this.id = id; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}

...

DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = ...
dynamoDBMapper.batchLoad(products);  // TODO is description loaded? what is the amount of Consumed Read Capacity Units?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As their [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.CapacityUnits):

> DynamoDB calculates the number of read capacity units consumed based on item size, not on the amount of data that is returned to an application. For this reason, the number of capacity units consumed will be the same whether you request all of the attributes (the default behavior) or just some of them (using a projection expression). The number will also be the same whether or not you use a filter expression.

As you see, projections does not impact on the amount of capacity units used.

BTW, in your case, `description` field will be returned anyway, because you do not need to annotate every field with DynamoDB annotation, only those, who are keys, or named differently, or need custom converters. All non-annotated fields will populated from the corresponding DB fields automatically.